# R or Python: relating extracted data AND images from pdf

Tags: python, r, pdf

I am trying to extract data and images from a pdf and pass them to a database. I had tried several libraries/packages in R and Python, nut still facing the problem that I can not relate the extracted image with the data which describes it.
I attached an image of a pdf file as a sample to illustrate the problem.
[image]
My need is to finally have a dataframe as follows:

```
NUMBER    ORDER  IMAGE
09090087  345679  345679.jpg
09090087  535278  535278.jpg
```

And the files 345679.jpg, which is a cat, and 535278.jpg, which is a dog, extracted to some folder...

At the moment I have managed to extract images but I can not figure out how to relate the image with text labels.

My code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import fitz
import sys, time, re

checkXO = r"/Type(?= */XObject)"       
checkIM = r"/Subtype(?= */Image)"          

doc = fitz.open(sys.argv[1])
imgcount = 0
lenXREF = doc._getXrefLength()        


for i in range(1, lenXREF):            
    text = doc._getObjectString(i)    
    isXObject = re.search(checkXO, text)    
    isImage   = re.search(checkIM, text)    
    if not isXObject or not isImage:   
        continue
    imgcount += 1
    pix = fitz.Pixmap(doc, i)          
    if pix.n < 5:                      
        pix.writePNG("pdfimg/img-%s.png" % (i,))
    else:                              
        pix0 = fitz.Pixmap(fitz.csRGB, pix)
        pix0.writePNG("pdfimg/img-%s.png" % (i,))
        pix0 = None                    
    pix = None
```

ANY ideas?

Comment: Please show your code - what have you done so far? Also, can you post a sample PDF?

Comment: @Watty62 I update with the code I used to extract images from pdf. I do not know how to load a pdf file to the question.

Comment: You could drop the file [here](https://www.filedropper.com)

Comment: @Watty, Thanks! here is the pdf [link](http://www.filedropper.com/sample_99)

Comment: @Watty62, Thanks! here is the pdf [link](http://www.filedropper.com/sample_99)

Comment: The file is not available anymore. Could you provide a new link?